# Webform: how to display warning message, when clicking upload, and no file is chosen?

Tags: webforms

I have a webform, in which I have file upload.

However, when user chooses no file, he is still able to click upload and nothing happens. I would like to have there similar message like when he chooses file with extension which is not allowed. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use jquery for custom validations. when user will click that button popup one error message.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the client side validaiton module install it then configure it for webforms , you could also use the module's hooks to customise error messages or create custom error handling functions  [client side validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation)

Comment: I have no clue, how to use that to achieve my goal. I tried to use hook_file_validate, but apparently, it doesn't go within that hook, when you don't attach file

Comment: @rukya, Can u please mention the code which u have written to validate for file upload??